# Javascript get element height not working

Tags: javascript

I need to toggle button based on element height. Tried offsetHeight, clientHeight and scrollHeight, none of those work. Set alert() for testing purposes, aways return undefined.

```
    window.onload = function (){
    var wrapperHeight = document.getElementsByClassName("panel").offsetHeight;
    var innerHeight = document.getElementsByClassName("description-content").offsetHeight;
    var button = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    if(innerHeight > wrapperHeight){
        button.style.display = "block";
    }
    alert(innerHeight);
}
```

Comment: when you use element.getElementsByClassName it does not return a single element. instead it returns some sort of an ElementList. to handle that just add [0] after the selector to select the first element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put `[0]` after the selector `document.getElementsByClassName("panel")`,
because `document.getElementsByClassName("panel")` returns a list (array) of elements with class "panel", then I recommend to use IDs and put `document.getElementById("panel_id");` instead to avoid these probs.

Here's your code: (With classes)

```
window.onload = function (){
    var wrapperHeight = document.getElementsByClassName("panel")[0].outerHeight;
    var innerHeight = document.getElementsByClassName("description-content")[0].outerHeight;
    var button = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion")[0];
    if(innerHeight > wrapperHeight){
        button.style.display = "block";
    }
    alert(innerHeight);
}
```

And here's your code (with IDs):

```
window.onload = function (){
        var wrapperHeight = document.getElementById("panel_id").outerHeight;
        var innerHeight = document.getElementById("description-content_id").outerHeight;
        var button = document.getElementById("accordion_id");
        if(innerHeight > wrapperHeight){
            button.style.display = "block";
        }
        alert(innerHeight);
    }
```

Comment: The problem with js style.height is that i need to set inline css rule to element. I´d like to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use style.height property. Try this one:

```
window.onload = function (){
    var wrapperHeight = document.getElementsByClassName("panel")[0].style.height;
    var innerHeight = document.getElementsByClassName("description-content")[0].style.height;
    var button = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    if(innerHeight > wrapperHeight){
        button.style.display = "block";
    }
    alert(innerHeight);
}
```